# API client for a package shipping system

Tags: python, object-oriented, json, client

I would like to implement a higher level design pattern here but I am a bit stumped, How can I improve this code and make it more object oriented?

```
import __builtin__
import logging
import requests
import json
import datetime
from string import Template
from resource_helpers.abort_logger import AbortLogger

CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE = Template("Attempting to connect to: $url")
CONNECTION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE = Template("Successfully connected to: $url")
CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE = Template("Unable to connect to: $url; Error Message: $error")
STATUS_CODE_ERROR_MESSAGE = Template("Unable to retrieve record from: $url; HTTP Status Code: $status_code")


class APIConnector(object): # pragma: no cover

    def __init__(self, auth_token, x_request_id):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.debug("APIConnector instantiated")
        self.logger.info('X-Request-Id: ' + x_request_id)
        self.get_headers = {'authorization': "Bearer " + auth_token,'X-Request-Id': x_request_id}
        self.post_headers = {'authorization': "Bearer " + auth_token, 'X-Request-Id': x_request_id,
                             'Content-type': 'application/json'}
        self.item_shipment_url = __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment][
                                        'item_endpoint'] + \
                                    __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment][
                                        'shipment_status']
        self.item_events_url = __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment][
                                     'item_endpoint'] + \
                                 __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment][
                                     'events_path']
        self.item_delivery_report_url = (
        __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment]['item_endpoint']
        + __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment][
            'item_post_path'])
        self.post_rules_sample_control_report_url = (
        __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment]['rule_endpoint']
        + __builtin__.environment_config[__builtin__.study_id][__builtin__.environment]['rule_path'])

    def get_item_shipment_status(self, package_id):
        self.logger.debug("Checking if package id: " + str(package_id) + " is in item ecosystem.")
        url = self.item_shipment_url + package_id
        try:
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url))
            request = requests.get(url, headers=self.get_headers)
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url))
        except Exception as e:
            AbortLogger.log_and_abort(500, self.logger.error,
                                      CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url, error=str(e)))
            raise
        else:
            if request.status_code != 200:
                AbortLogger.log_and_abort(request.status_code, self.logger.error,
                                          STATUS_CODE_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url,
                                                                               status_code=request.status_code))
            else:
                return request

    def post_item_events_path(self, item_dictionary, package_id):
        self.logger.info("Posting json to item Ecosystem for: " + package_id)
        try:
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_events_url))
            request = requests.post(self.item_events_url, data=json.dumps(item_dictionary), headers=self.post_headers)
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_events_url))
        except Exception as e:
            AbortLogger.log_and_abort(500, self.logger.error,
                                      CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_events_url, error=str(e)))
            raise
        else:
            if request.status_code != 200:
                AbortLogger.log_and_abort(request.status_code, self.logger.error,
                                          STATUS_CODE_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_events_url,
                                                                               status_code=request.status_code))
            else:
                return request

    def post_item_delivery_report(self, item_dictionary, package_id):
        self.logger.info("Posting tsv file name to item Ecosystem for: " + package_id)
        try:
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_delivery_report_url + package_id))
            request = requests.post(self.item_delivery_report_url + package_id, data=json.dumps(item_dictionary),
                                    headers=self.post_headers)
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_delivery_report_url + package_id))
        except Exception as e:
            AbortLogger.log_and_abort(500, self.logger.error,
                                      CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(
                                          url=self.item_delivery_report_url + package_id) + str(e))
            raise
        else:
            if request.status_code != 202:
                AbortLogger.log_and_abort(request.status_code, self.logger.error,
                                          STATUS_CODE_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=self.item_delivery_report_url,
                                                                               status_code=request.status_code))
            else:
                self.logger.info("Successfully posted TSV file name to item Ecosystem for: " + package_id)
                return request

    def post_rules_sample_control_report(self, control_type, dictionary):
        self.logger.info("Posting to rules engine.")
        url = '{}{}/{}/{}/{}/{}?format=tsv'.format(self.post_rules_sample_control_report_url, control_type,
                                                   dictionary['package_reporter_id'], dictionary['package_id'],
                                                   dictionary['analysis_id'],
                                                   dictionary['pdf_name'].split(".")[0])
        try:
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_ATTEMPT_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url))
            request = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps([]),
                                    headers=self.post_headers)
            self.logger.info(CONNECTION_SUCCESS_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url))
        except Exception as e:
            AbortLogger.log_and_abort(500, self.logger.error,
                                      CONNECTION_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url, error= str(e)))
            raise
        else:
            if request.status_code != 200:
                AbortLogger.log_and_abort(request.status_code, self.logger.error,
                                          STATUS_CODE_ERROR_MESSAGE.substitute(url=url,
                                                                               status_code=request.status_code))
            else:
                self.logger.info("Successfully posted to: " + url)
                for key, value in request.json().iteritems():
                    dictionary.update({key: value})
                    dictionary.update({'date_delivery_received': str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())})
                return dictionary
```

Comment: You should probably ask in Code Review

Comment: I would factor out the error handling and make wrappers for `requests.get` and `requests.post` that do logging and the let the methods deal with only the success or failure.

Comment: @danD. I am not quite sure what you mean, could you give me an example?